# database search with sqlite3 python error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def dashboard():
    
    p = request.form['Pseudo']
    
    if cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pseudo WHERE user = '?'", (p,)) == 0:
        
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO pseudo (user, score, win, coup) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (p,0,0,0))
        conn.commit()
        
    else:
        pass
    
    return render_template("index.html",data=liste, Pseudo = p)
```

error : sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

hello, I've been stuck for several hours and I don't understand why I'm making a mistake.
with this program is an ongoing project and here I want to check if the pseudo is already in use and if it is not used, register it in the database

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around the `?`.

Comment: Don't put the `?` placeholder inside quotes. That searches for a literal `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting your table definition to avoid multiple queries with conditional logic:

**SQLite**

```sql
CREATE TABLE pseudo (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user   VARCHAR UNIQUE,        -- UNIQUE REQUIRED FOR IGNORE
    score  INTEGER DEFAULT 0,  
    win    INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    coup   INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
```

**Python**

```py
def dashboard():
    p = request.form['Pseudo']
    
    cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO pseudo (user) VALUES (?)", (p,))
    conn.commit()

    ...

    return render_template("index.html", data=liste, Pseudo=p)
```